# Numpy percentiles with linear interpolation - wrong value?

Tags: python, numpy, percentile, linear-interpolation

The linear interpolation formula for percentiles is:

> linear: i + (j - i) * fraction, where fraction is the fractional part of the index surrounded by i and j.

Suppose I have this list with 16 observations:

```
test = [0, 1, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 11, 12, 21, 23, 23, 24]
```

I pass it as a numpy array and calculate the 85th percentile using linear interpolation.

```
np_test = np.asarray(test)
np.percentile(np_test, 85, interpolation = 'linear')
```

The result I get is *22.5*. However, I don't think that's correct. The index of the 85th percentile is .85 * 16 = 13.6. Thus, the fractional part is .6. 
The 13th value is 21, so i = 21. The 14th value is 23, so j = 23. The linear formula should then yield:

> 21 + (23 - 21) * .6 = 21 + 2 * .6 = 21 + 1.2 = 22.2

The correct answer is **22.2**. Why am I getting 22.5 instead?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`len(test)` is 16 but the *distance* between last element and first element is 1 less, that is, `d=16-1=15-0=15`. Therefore, index of 85th percentile is `d*0.85 = 15*0.85 = 12.75`. `test[12] = 21` and `test[13] = 23`. Therefore, using linear interpolation for the fractional part, we get: `21 + 0.75 * (23 - 21) = 22.5`. The correct answer is **22.5**.

From the **Notes** section of the documentation of `numpy.percentile()`:

> Given a vector V of length N, the q-th percentile of V is the value q/100 of the way from the mimumum to the maximum in in a sorted copy of V.

The key here is, in my opinion, *"the way from the minimum to the maximum"*. Let's say we number elements from 1 to 16. Then the "position" of the first element is 1 and the "position" (along the "coordinate axis of indices") of the last element in `test` is 16. Therefore the *distance* between them is `16-1=15`.

Comment: Why is it going by maximum index? Shouldn't it be going by number of observations? Is there a way around this?

Comment: @JerinVarghese If you want to use a different definition, e.g., expecting this function to use the number of elements instead of distance between them, I can imagine you could append a number that is smaller than any other element in the array/list, for example, `test.append(min(test)-1)`. This should do the trick.

Comment: @JerinVarghese You are welcome! Just be careful not to use `q<1/N` because then it will interpolate between the `min(test)` and an arbitrary value `min(test)-1` (it is arbitrary because you could have used `min(test)-100` to implement the trick). Therefore the result will be garbage.